# Calling a a method that creates a class instance sees wrong types of variables

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time finding my issue.

I have a class called Prodcut:

```java
class Product extends ObjectIDs implements Output  {

    private String prodName;
    private int quantity;
    private Double cost;
```

It also has an `Id` variable that it get's from a different class. It's a String type. Generally every Product instance would be something like this: `Product P = new Prodcut(String, String, int, double)`

Moving on, I have a `Store` class that I create everything in. I have a method called `newProdcut` that allows me to create a new Product and return it:

```java
Product newProdcut(String id, String prodName, Integer prodQuantity, Double prodCost) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for ( Product p : products ) {
            if ( id.equals(p.id)) {
                System.out.println("Product already exists, please enter the number of the quantity you want to add to the existing quantity:");
                int inputQuantity = sc.nextInt();
                prodQuantity += inputQuantity;
            }
        }
        Product p = new Product(id, prodName, prodQuantity, prodCost);
        this.products.add(p);
        System.out.println("Prodcut "+p.createOutput()+" was added to the list");
        return p;
    }
```

Now, I also have a console menu that calls this function and populates an ArrayList with the return:

```java
   private static ArrayList<String> menuAddProdcut() throws Exception { // 1. Add a prodcut
       Random rand = new Random();
       System.out.println("You're adding a new prodcut");
       ArrayList newProductArray = new ArrayList<>();      
       int prodId = rand.nextInt(1000) + 100;
       String prodIdStr = Integer.toString(prodId); 
       System.out.println("Enter product name:");
       String prodName = sc.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Enter quantity:");
       Integer prodQuantity = sc.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter product's price:");
       Double price = sc.nextDouble();
       newProductArray.add(prodIdStr); //str-converted ID
       newProductArray.add(prodName);
       newProductArray.add(prodQuantity);
       newProductArray.add(price);

       return newProductArray;         
   }
```

Then, I'm calling this method from the menu:

```java
   case 1:
       try {
         ArrayList<String> productToPopulate = Menu.menuAddProdcut();
         st.newProdcut(productToPopulate.get(0), productToPopulate.get(1), productToPopulate.get(2), productToPopulate.get(3));
      } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

I get the followung error:

`The method newProdcut(String, String, Integer, Double) in the type Store is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String)`

I don't understand why it thinks the input should be all Strings when clearly, in the Prodcut, it says String String int double.

Any help would be great.

Comment: The last snippet doesn't seem to be related at all. And you didn't post a part where you actually call `newProdcut()`

Comment: Other than that, if you have a List declared as `ArrayList<String>` all of it's elements are Strings so you can't just take any of them and expect it to suddenly become an Integer.

Comment: That error means that on some part of your code you are calling the method using 4 Strings as parameters, and not two Strings an int and a double.

Comment: @Amongalen my bad, I pasted the wrong function in the menu. I fixed it now. It might actually still be because I'm declaring String type ArrayList...

Comment: read the error message and it says "not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String)" the two last arguments of newProduct is Integer and Double. See the difference?

Comment: @Voodoo I see that but I don't know where it's getting it from, I pasted the `newProdcut` method, it's not in it. It's also not anything inside the Prodcut class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of method `newProdcut` requires arguments of type `(String, String, Integer, Double)` whereas in the bit of code where you are calling the method, you're passing 4 Strings.

Using `Integer.parseInt(String)`, and `Double.parseDouble(String)` methods to convert your 3rd and 4rd arguments into the appropriate types.

---

As an alternative fix, instead of storing the user's input in an ArrayList of Strings in `menuAddProduct`, you've already got the data stored in variable form, call your method directly after user input.

Comment: Thanks! Are you referring to this line: `st.newProdcut(productToPopulate.get(0), productToPopulate.get(1), productToPopulate.get(2), productToPopulate.get(3));`?

Comment: Yes, just convert your last 2 arguments to the correct type using the methods I mentioned above.

Comment: I tried something like this:

`ArrayList<String> productToPopulate = Menu.menuAddProdcut();
                        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(productToPopulate.get(2));
                        Double cost = Double.parseDouble(productToPopulate.get(3));
                        st.newProdcut(productToPopulate.get(0), productToPopulate.get(1), productToPopulate.get(quantity), productToPopulate.get(cost));`
It didn't work still.

Comment: Why are you doing `productToPopulate.get()` when you've already fetched the integer and double values for quantity and cost already? Just put `st.newProdcut(productToPopulate.get(0), productToPopulate.get(1), quantity, cost);`